# Why do Auto Constraints for distance from the sides have to be negative for fullscreen?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uistoryboard, ios-autolayout

Why does my Auto Constraints for distance from the sides have to be negative for the `UIImageView` to align with the sides of the `UIViewController`. In the screenshot below, notice that right side (aligned) is -20 and on the left side it is -14 and there is some empty space between the edges of the `UIImageView` and `UIViewController`.

Why is a negative number needed here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck "Constrain to margins" and you will get positive values there.